# Is the new vaccine better?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

A vaccine for Covid-19 is known to be $90\%$ effective, i.e. $90\%$ of vaccine recipients are successfully immunised against Covid-19. A new (different) vaccine is tested on $100$ patients and found to successfully immunise $96$ of the $100$ patients. Is the new vaccine better?

Hint: Assume the new vaccine is equally effective as the original vaccine and consider using an appropriate distribution.

I am not sure how to tackle this problem, but my answer is:

Not necessarily, since the sample is $100$ and it is unknown what is the sample of the first vaccine, hence we cannot know whether the second vaccine is better.

What's the correct way to answer this problem?

Comment: Usually, one is given a confidence level.  That is, assume that the second is the same as the first and ask if the probability of the observed outcome is below the specified confidence level.

Comment: @lulu perhaps "the observed outcome or a more extreme outcome"

Comment: yes, every $ is effective to the producer! :)

Comment: It's pertinent to point out this error in the exercise's storyline even though it doesn't affect the thrust of the solution: vaccine effectiveness does ***not*** refer to the percentage of recipients successfully immunised!! Nor does it refer to how frequently the vaccine blocks infection, nor the recipient's chance of non-infection (which depends on the disease prevalence, their exposure, safety measures, state of health, etc.).

Comment: Rather, vaccine effectiveness measures **increase in protection**: $90\%$ effective technically means that in any given situation, one is $10$ times as likely to be infected without the vaccine than with. More details in my [explainer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/97797/63723).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an Hypothesis Test exercise.

Consider as the null hypothesis of 90% success a binomial distribution. The extreme probability

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 96|p=0.9]\approx 2.40\%$$

Thus you can reject the hypothesis that the old vaccine is better than the new one with a p-value equal or less than 2.4%

this means that the test is significant but not higly significant.

Usually the test is significant if $\text{p-value} < 5%$ and highly significant if $\text{p-value}<1\%$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. How did you calculate 2.40%?

Comment: @user: $\sum_{x=96}^{100}\binom{100}{x}(0.9)^x(0.1)^{100-x}$

Comment: thank you. can you answer the other comments? Thank you!